# What does the Encoding function in R do and is there a Python equivalent?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, function, character-encoding

I'm translating R into Python and there is a line of code that says

Encoding(item) == 'UTF-8'

where item is some character vector.
What does this line of code mean and how do I replicate it in Python?

Comment: add
# !/usr/bin/python 
# coding:utf-8
to your header

Comment: why should I do that?

Comment: Because [Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: you can try `bytes_item.decode("utf-8")` and if you get error then it is not text in `utf-8` - and you can catch error with `try/except`. There is also module `chardet` (character detection). But it seems [Encoding](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Encoding) is assigning encoding to string but Python use always `UNICODE` for string and it can convert to bytes with encoding `UTF-8` `latin1`, etc.

Comment: @Zhubei-Federer: Is it really needed? Python3 assumes automatically source in UTF-8, and this question is not about the encoding of th source code, but about dynamic encode/decode.

Comment: Are you sure that you had such line in R? (check if markdown editor of this site distorted your original text). Is it really `==` or just `<-`, so to define the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3+, str is always stored in UTF-8.

You can encode it in other encoding scheme, like

```
>>> x='욜로'; y = x.encode('CP949')
>>> type(y)
<class 'bytes'>
```

And the result is `bytes` class which is just a stream of bytes.

It does not have any information of what it stores or in which encoding,

because bytes can be anything(string, integer, floats...).

If you are sure that a variable in byte is a string,

you can guess which encoding it is encoded in, like

```
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(y)
{'encoding': 'ISO-8859-1', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
```

so if `type(item)` is `str`, it is always `True`,
and if `type(item)` is `bytes`, you might use `chardet.detect(y)['encoding']` but it is not garaunteed true all the time